# Python IMAP getting emails before a date, and also UNSEEN

Tags: python, imap

So I know how to get emails that are unseen
And I know how to get emails before a certain date.
But how do I combine these 2 to get all emails that are unseen before a certain date?

```
conn = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com", 993)
typ, data = conn.search(None, 'BEFORE', before_date) //before a date
typ, data = conn.search(None, 'UNSEEN') //all un seen
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put your two conditions one after the other, like this:

```
typ, data = conn.search(None, 'BEFORE', before_date, 'UNSEEN')
```

Reference: section 6.4.4 of the IMAP RFC (RFC3501) says this:

> When multiple keys are specified, the result is the intersection
>   (AND function) of all the messages that match those keys.  For
>   example, the criteria DELETED FROM "SMITH" SINCE 1-Feb-1994 refers
>   to all deleted messages from Smith that were placed in the mailbox
>   since February 1, 1994.

-Phil